# pass multiple parameter in an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass three parameters to this `onclick()` function. but it gives me a syntax error.

```
element += '<div class="cancel" onclick="remove_game(' + game.id + ',\'' + cellstyle + ',\'' + cellid +'\');">';
```

It calls the function correctly, but it gives the error below

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list


remove_game(6,'2, 'game6-cell2);
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `'`'s and commas are off, so that the second argument appears to be `'2, '`, and then there isn't a comma before the third.  Assuming you want quotes around the 3rd argument, you'd need something like this:

`element += '<div class="cancel" onclick="remove_game(' + game.id + ',' + cellstyle + ',\'' + cellid +'\');">';`

Comment: can you show it me with corrected syntax please. I tried it sevaral ways

Answer (score 2):

Tada

```
var element = document.createElement('div');

element.className = 'cancel';
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    remove_game(game.id, cellstyle, cellid);
}, false);
```

Comment: I have to follow above flow because its a sub element of another element. Thanks for the help

Comment: Then you should create that element the same way as this, and append this element to that element using `appendChild`